# Get Tuesday and Wednesday next week, with Linux date command

Tags: linux, unix

At a Linux shell, you can do something like:

```
date -d "next Tuesday"
```

To get next Tuesday.

My issue is this:
I want to get Tuesday of NEXT WEEK. So if I'm currently on Monday, I want it to go 7 days forward to next week, then evaluate "next Tuesday". Is there a way to chain the date evaluations somehow?

To further elaborate, if I am on a Wednesday, then next week's Tuesday is just 6 days away

Comment: Add that as an edit to the question.

Comment: `bash` *has* no `date` command. When you run `date`, it's a separate operating system component, not part of bash.

Comment: That's important, because what you can do in `date` differs between operating systems even if they're all running bash: MacOS, for instance, has BSD date, which is much less capable than the GNU version common on Linux; the answers here all depend on GNU date (and *don't* depend at all on bash; they'll work fine with ksh or ash or calling `date` straight from Python or Java or C with no shell at all).

Answer (score 9):

`date` is cleverer than you'd think

```
~: date -d "next tuesday"
Tue Feb  2 00:00:00 GMT 2016
~: date -d "1 week next tuesday"
Tue Feb  9 00:00:00 GMT 2016
~:
```

If you want to get the Tuesday of next week you can find the start of next week, then add a day

```
~: date -d "1 day next monday"
Tue Feb  2 00:00:00 GMT 2016
```

If you want it to be slightly clear you can use

```
~: date -d "next Monday + 1 day"
Tue Feb  2 00:00:00 GMT 2016
```

Based on Charles Duffy's comments it might be worth noting on my machine

```
~: date --version #on RHEL6
date (GNU coreutils) 8.4
<license stuff (GPLv3)>
```

Comment: Why is the time different?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I think it's reading the `a` as a time format -- fixed

Comment: The problem with this is you need to know ahead of time if today is before or after Tuesday.

Comment: @chepner, not sure if that was what the OP was after but if you wanted you could do `date -d "1 day next monday"` to ensure you get the Tuesday of next week

Comment: No, that gives you the Wednesday that is 2 days after next Monday.

Comment: I don't know any way of forcing `date` to treat "next" relative to the next beginning-of-the-week.

Comment: @chepner, I changed it from 2 to 1. That works for me. Using `next monday` gets the beginning of the next week. `1 day` gets the tuesday after that.

Comment: No, you're still getting the next monday after (today + 1 day). Try `1 day next Thursday`.

Comment: @chepner, if you want Thursday next week, use `3 days next Monday`

Comment: @Holloway: The point chepner is making is "(next monday after today) + 1 day" vs "next monday after (today + 1 day)", which is a completely valid objection... however, it clearly *isn't* doing the latter interpretation, since that parsing would give a monday.

Comment: @chepner: No, it isn't "getting the next monday after (today + 1 day)" since that would BE a Monday.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to do this reliably is to first get the next "beginning of week day" (which might vary from region to region; for this I'll assume it's Sunday), then request a day 0-6 days in the future, where 0 through 6 stand in for Sunday through Saturday, respectively.

```
$ bow=$(date -d "next Sunday")
$ date -d "$bow + 0 days"
```